# Why is the texture sideways/diagonal?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I'm in blender cycles and my image, when rendered, looks like this.
[image]

Why is it sideways/diagonal in some places.

Comment: How are we supposed to know with such little info? How did you texture it, did you unwrap, generated coordinates, object UVs? What kind of material setup do you have, how are your nodes set up?. Please edit your question and provide more info, possibly some screenshots of your materials and node setup.

Comment: How did you map the image on the shader?

Comment: To learn about texture coordinates I suggest that you watch Bartek Skorupa's video:[Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0)